# how to give dynamic path to the $.get method of jquery

Tags: jquery

i am writing a function to load highcharts data from a .csv file. but i am having some problem in providing the file path to the jquery's .get method. 
Here is my method

```
    $.get('data.csv', function(data)) {.......}
```

my file 'data.csv' is placed in a path: "myproject/public/data.csv" and my $.get function is written in a 'index.js' file which is located at path:

```
    myproject/public/media/js/modules/testapp/index/index.js
```

please help me in providing the correct path to the data.csv file. my application is in zend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the HTML document specify the base URL for you call.

```
<script>
var baseUrl = "http://myproject.com/apis/";
</script>
```

Then use it in your file myproject/public/media/js/modules/testapp/index/index.js

> $.get( window.baseUrl + 'data.csv', function(data)) {.......}

Answer (score 0):

I use a whack (/) to set the start of the path to the domain level and access files that way.  Try this:

```
$.get('/public/data.csv', function(data)) {.......}
```

Comment: but i don't want to hardcode the path. i am passing a variable with the path. but it seems like when i pass only the filename in the variable, the method works fine, but if i pass a long path along with filename then it doesn't work. like this: $file = data.csv ; $.get($file, function(data) .... // it works fine, but if it is like $file = projectpath/filename; $.get($file, function(data).... // then it doesn't work.

Comment: That is not normal behaviour for paths. Is there any more information you can give us that would help? Like, how is this .js file included in your web page? Is there a sample we can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery JavaScript code is running at the client side (in a browser), so you need to specify the complete/full address:

```
$.get('http://www.yourdomain.com/data.csv', function(data)) {
```

(of course replace `www.yourdomain.com` with your actual URL)

You could also try to load the file directly in your browser (again with the same complete/full address), if that works you found the correct address.